Resolution to the "Ladder Movers' Problem"?
A problem that has been discussed before on this site has recently resurfaced on X. Namely:

Two painters are carrying a 20-foot ladder, one at each end, along a garden path which begins and ends with long straight segments. Can they negotiate the path without violating the "keep off the grass" sign?

Based on the previous question linked above, it seems that it's known that the answer is:

yes, if the path is piecewise-linear;
not necessarily, if the path is continuous and rectifiable.

This situation is not too satisfying, since piecewise-linearity is a very strong restriction---I expect the property to hold for most "reasonable" smooth curves someone might draw.
Are there weaker conditions than piecewise-linearity for which it's known that the answer is "yes"?

This may or may not be of interest: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Chee-Yap/publication/37464843_Mountain_Climbing_Ladder_Moving_and_the_Ring-Width_of_a_Polygon/links/0912f50f8306979327000000/Mountain-Climbing-Ladder-Moving-and-the-Ring-Width-of-a-Polygon.pdf

@fleablood Unless I'm missing something, that paper agrees with what I wrote above: the statement is always true for piecewise-linear curves, and there is a counterexample for a continuous and rectifiable curve.

Is there a reason the paper shouldn't have agreed?  You asked if there was a canonic resolution (even though you yourself provided an answer).  I assumed you were looking for confirmation if your answer was correct.  (If you only wanted a different answer then why do your provide your answer? Did you think it was wrong or something?)

Presumably the OP's main question is the last sentence; they could edit to clarify that. OP, maybe you could be more specific about what you mean by "canonical resolution" as well.

@GregMartin I've edited an attempt to refine my question.
